# Starting a conversation on Dialogflow, lowercase /start not working

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram, telegram-bot, api-ai

I am building a Chat Bot with Dialogflow and Telegram - Python Flask web hook.

I am having trouble starting the conversation.

When I type '/Start', with a capital 'S' then is works. When I type '/start' with a lowercase 's', then it fails with the fall back intent.

I deleted the default welcome intent.

How do I start the conversion with the lowercase '/start' as well as the uppercase start '/Start'.

Thanks

Comment: Same thing seams to be happening with /help and /Help. /help fails.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/platform-events) there are two events that you have to add to your intent: TELEGRAM_HELP for /help and TELEGRAM_WELCOME for /start.

I have just tried this and it works in my bot.
[image]